# can i get lost images/ videos from broken phone if i had a google account

Tags: lg

I lost all the pictures and videos on my last phone because it got wet and wouldn't come back on. On this new phone (same exact phone as broken one) under settings> backup & recover its was already set to automatically back up files so I'm assuming the old one was too. But I don't know what I need to do to find them or get them back. I have the info for my old google account but I also set up a new account when I got this phone

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled sync with Google Photos, you would find it here: https://photos.google.com/